# Android RecyclerView: how to add new item to top of list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cursor

I have a `SQLite database` that pushes data to a `CardView` for a `RecyclerView` list.  I want newly added `CardViews` to insert at the top of the list but they are being added at the bottom, the end of the list.

It seems like this code in the `MainActivity` is not being respected that should put the new `CardView` at the top of the list:

```
contactList.add(0, contact);
```

What am I missing here?

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    loadData();
}

void loadData(){
    sqLiteDB = new SQLiteDB(this);

    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDB.retrieve();
    Contact contact;

    // iterate over the db cursor by using a new cursor for the ArrayList.
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { // to avoid an infinite loop iteration.
                do {
                    contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    contact.setTodo(cursor.getString(1));

                    **contactList.add(0, contact);** // add the new item to top of R. list.
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if(cursor !=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    contactListAdapter.clear();
    contactListAdapter.addAll(contactList);
```

**SQLiteDB.java**

```
public Cursor retrieve(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {
            ContactField.COLUMN_ID,
            ContactField.COLUMN_TODO
    };

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            ContactField.TABLE_NAME,projection,              
            null,                    
            null,                    
            null,                    
            null,                    
            null                     
    );

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return cursor;
}
```

**ContactListAdapter.java**

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactListAdapter.ContactHolder>{

private List<Contact> contactList;
private Context context;
private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;
// Setting to -1 keeps the first CardView (position 0) from having its
// BackGroundColor mistakenly switch from the default to the highlighted/selected
// color which is red.
private int selectedPos = -1;

public ContactListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void clear() {
    while (getItemCount() > 0) {
        remove(getItem(0));
    }
}

public void addAll(List<Contact> contactList) {
    for (Contact contact : contactList) {
        // add(contact);
        contactList.add(0, contact);        }
}

// Get the Item's position.
public Contact getItem(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position);
}

// Get the Item's Id.
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position).getId();
}
...
```

Comment: You should remove the inner do/while and just leave `cursor.moveToNext()`. Also check if inside your `addAll` method, the contacts are in the right order.  Also remember to call `contactListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after modifying the list of the adapter.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to remove the inner do/while.  How would I check if the contacts are in the right order inside addAll method?

Comment: You can put a breakpoint and debug or you could just print each Contact to see if they were loaded in order.

Comment: Yes, ok...being working on this too long...need to pull back and re-focus on the big picture!

Comment: @AJW I think your code doesn't have any problem if you are calling `addAll()` method once in a complete life cycle of your application. Is it the case? or are you calling it repeatedly whenever there are database changes?

Comment: I start with an empty database.  I add a CardView and addAll() method runs.  Later I add a second CardView and addAll() runs again and the CardView is added to the RecyclerView list View below the original CardView.  I'm looking for the second CardView to be added at the top of the list View.

Comment: @indramurari sorry, to answer your question it is called repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding element to start in following snippet(refer comment at `contactList.add(contact);` line)

```
try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { // to avoid an infinite loop iteration.
                do {
                    contact = new Contact();
                    contact.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                    contact.setTodo(cursor.getString(1));

                    contactList.add(contact); // just add the new item to list normally.
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if(cursor !=null && !cursor.isClosed()){
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

just change your addAll() method as follows

```
public void addAll(List<Contact> contactList) {
    for (Contact contact : contactList) {
        //add(contact);
        yourList.add(0, contact);
    }
}
```

Also in `clearAll` method just write `youList.clear()`

Comment: Ah, ok I will give that a try.

Comment: So I understand correctly, "yourList" above would be my "contactList"?

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.  Upon testing , the first CardView added returned a blank RecyclerView list, so something happened with the View.  The second CardView crashed the app.

Comment: Ok I will load above.

Comment: I added additional code...the remaining code is in the ViewHolder and onBindViewHolder sections that is probably not affected.

Comment: @AJW Have you changed `cotactList.add(0, contact)` to `contactList.add(contact)` in `loadData()` method

Comment: Yes, I did that before I tested the app.

Comment: @AJW also i couldn't understand why you have written code in onStart() instead write it in onCreate itself

Comment: I was just trying out the code with onStart() to test behavior.  I can easily put in onCreate.

Comment: @AJW Ok give it a try and by my answer it must work. There is not any complx logic. Please check once again if you are doing as i have told

Comment: Do you think putting the loadData code into onCreate will put all new CardViews to the top of the list...I wonder if onCreate will have anything to do with the position of the CardViews.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @AJW No. Is doesn't have any effect if you put it in onCreate or onStart as far as you completely understand activity lifecycle.

Comment: OK I removed the onStart() code and put all of in onCreate() of the MainActivity.  I also changed the clear() method to be "contactList.clear();"  Unfortunately I get the same result.  The first Cardview results in a blank RecyclerView list.  The second CardView that is added crashes the app.

Comment: @AJW Have you put Recycler View in cardview? Or cardview in Recycler view as item?

Comment: Yes.  Before these codes changes, all was working fine.  The only issue was the order of the CardView insertions.  The second CardView added was being added to the RecyclerView correctly and the UI showed the addition but the CardView was at the bottom of the list and I want it to be at the top.

Comment: @AJW these code changes have nothing to do with android or view part. These are logical changes so It shouldn't affect or crash your code. Revoke to your code again and only do the changes mentioned in my answer. That might help you

Comment: Ok, I've run out of troubleshooting time for tonight.  I appreciate you helping me.  I will try again tomorrow and post any findings.  Cheers!

Comment: @AJW Thanks. Happy coding :-)